# PHP OOP processing

Tags: php, oop

Hey guys so I got few concerns at the moment, I need some explanation on how is this processed for players.

```
<?php 

    class Person {
        public $name;

        public function setName($newName) {
            $this->setName($newName);
        }
    }

    $handler = new Person();

    $hander->setName("Test");
?>
```

Lets take that code as an example, and lets say PLAYER 1 logs into the site and gets his name set with setName. Now how does the PHP knows that its bound to that player? For example when another player connects and I do the same thing, will it overlap the first one or will it stay separate?
For example

```
$handler->setName("Person 1"); //when the first person logs in set their name to Person 1
$handler->setName("Person 1"); //when the second person logs in set their name to Person 2
```

will the PHP know who is set to what or? I dont understand... For example in SA:MP scripting I had PLAYERID which I used to assign to variables and such, is there anything as such here? Do I need something like PLAYERID for this or?

Comment: it doesn't. every php script invocation is completely independent of every other invocation. nothing is persisted between script runs, unless you explicitly take steps to do that persistence. e.g. a php session.

Comment: So in this case, in noob words, it has that "playerid" built in? So every php script runs for every player when called separately?

Comment: no, it has no playerid or anything built in. when you hit a php url, the webserver fires up a copy of php, runs your script, then php exits and cleans up. nothing is preserved. if you set a variable in a script, that variable will NOT be there the next time the script runs.

Comment: Aha so when I click login for example and I just simply do $name = "Twinki"; it will just be MY name, and if you login and type $name = "Marc"; it wont change the variable $name for everyone, it will just set its value to yourself only?

Comment: exactly. ever script invocation is completely and utterly independent of every other one, even if the same script is requested by 2+ people at the same time. the only way data gets shared/persisted is if YOU take steps to make that happen.

Comment: In this case, it would have different names even in a different object (basic OOP)... A _good_ question would be in case the attribute were set as static (but MarcB's answer would still apply for static properties)

Comment: Ahaaa, thanks a lot Marc! I was wondering about this for 2 days, couldnt find a correct answer on google for this, they tend to speak in a rather too complicated way haha. Cheers mate!

Comment: It's unknown if you're using or planning to use a database with this. If that's the case, then the answer to this would be that, it would be known in using a `WHERE` clause, that's if that's what the *underlying* question's really about.

Comment: Yeah thought so FirstOne, its just I always had to work with these player-bound stuff where I had to index it for every player. For example in stuff that I worked in the past (non-php) $name would be for everyone, while $name[someone] would be just for someone exactly. PHP is really nice done there, I like the fact its just easy as that when it comes to player-bound stuff, I dont have to go thru huge complicated loops to do something :)
@Fred-ii- of course MySQL and yeah I get you, I was just wondering about this for soo long haha. I was worrying that if I set something it will share it haha

Comment: You could use sessions for this also, in conjunction with the `WHERE` clause. Once a session array's been assigned from said row(s), then the rest will/should follow. A session can be set from the login form (if you're using one), and assigned from the POST array (which is suggested) and checking to see if the session is set and equal to something in subsequent pages. I hope you have enough to go now with your project.

Comment: Aha thats whats the session is for aaaahhhh. I seen the things such as session_start. But overall as I get, its not needed which makes my life 1000x easier haha. Ill most likely handle it simple with PRIMARY key inside the SQL and assign that to players

Comment: You are creating an endless loop in setName(). It should read --- function setName($name) { $this->name = $name; }.

Comment: Considering the scope of the object, I believe each user will have a different object. For example, if you have something like $app = new App(); in index.php, each user gets an instance of the object which is unique to the user.